# Reduce redundant linear system of equations to non-redundant one

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a redundant system of linear equations
$A ~x = b$
where $A$ is an $M \times N$ matrix, and $A$ is not full rank, I would like to obtain another system of equations
$A' ~x = b'$
which is equivalent to the first one, but non redundant, i.e., with $A'$ full rank. How may I do this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "equivalent"?

Comment: Do you care about computational complexity?

Comment: @NiranjanKumar, I don't care about computational complexity

Comment: @AugustoSantos, by euivalent I mean a system of equations whose equations are linear combinations of the original one